# jcarousel issues

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I'm trying to do what I've seen many people try to do with jcarousel, which is, I'd like clear it and refill it dynamically.  I seem to have found a way to entirely clear the DOM of empty li items (a common complaint) but I then cannot seem to add items from a remote file. Here's my code:

```
$(function() {


$('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
   initCallback:carousel_callback
  });

function carousel_callback(carousel){
$('#live-edge-large img').click(function(){
carousel.size(0); // sets size to 0
$('#mycarousel').empty(); // empties ul
carousel.reset(); //clears DOM of li's
$.get('ajax/xml-content.php',
      {
          first: carousel.first,
            last: carousel.last
            },
    function(data) {
    mycarousel_itemAddCallback(carousel,carousel.first,carousel.last,data);
        },"xml"
        );
});
   };

function mycarousel_itemAddCallback(carousel,first,last,data) {
    carousel.size(parseInt(jQuery('total', xml).text()));
    $('image',xml).each(function(i) {
    carousel.add(first+i, mycarousel_getItemHTML($(this).text()));
    });
};

function mycarousel_getItemHTML(url)
{
    return'<img src="' + url + '" width="128" height="95" alt="" />';
};

});
```

The code is working until this line:

```
carousel.size(parseInt(jQuery('total', xml).text()));
```

Here's my php file with the xml:

```
<?php  
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");  
?>

<data> 
<total>3</total>
<image>images/thumbs/test-9-thumb.jpg</image> 
<image>images/thumbs/test-2-thumb.jpg</image>
<image>images/thumbs/test-3-thumb.jpg</image>
</data>
```

Not sure why I can't set the size and then add items to the carousel, maybe the size can't be reset in this way?  Any ideas? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

In your function mycarousel_itemAddCallback, replace 'xml' with 'data' and it should work...